# Bison - operator precedence

Tags: bison, operator-precedence

I have a question about operator precedence and associativity in Bison.

In every example I see the productions are like `expr 'op' expr`, for example :http://dinosaur.compilertools.net/bison/bison_8.html

But if I would use bison `%left`and others associativity tools, and I would use grammar like:

```
  expr|     expr binop expr
      |     expr relop expr
      |     expr logical_op expr
```

and

```
 binop: '+' 
      | '-' 
      | '*' 
      | '/' 
      ;
 relop: EE
      | NE
      | LE
      | '<'
      | GE
      | '>'
      ;
 logical_op: AND
           | OR
           ;
```

would associativity and precedence rules be used?

Or do I need to write explicite `expr 'op' expr` for every operator?

I am asking, because when I try to use the grammar like the one I posted I get warnings about conflicts.

But when by hand I write productions like `expr '+' expr` I am not getting any warnings.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For precedence rules to work, the terminal itself must appear in the ambiguous production. So you cannot group terminals into non-terminals and retain the ability to use precedence rules.

Comment: Thank you for confirming my suspicions.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to add grammar rules (productions) to account for operator precedence.  See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10972858/why-in-some-cases-i-cant-use-a-token-as-precedence-marker).

Comment: Interesting , I knew about this technique of making operator precedence be reflected by the grammar, but I wanted to use the tools that come with bison. Thanks anyway for reminding me of other possibility