# maximum munch rule with yacc/bison -- seems to be taking minimum munch

Tags: bison, yacc

I'm trying to introduce a new language construct into a large/complex grammar. I know it'll make the syntax ambiguous, but I'm hoping to resolve that with the 'maximum munch' rule. That is, put my construct first, so it's taken by preference. I've got some success, but other parts of the tree not so much. Consider:

```
( 1, 2, 3 )          // triple
( 4, 5 )             // twople
( 6 )                // *not* a oneple, see below
()                   // zerople

(7 + 8) * 9          // single parens used to override usual precedence
( (( 7 + 8 )) * 9 )  // currently this means the same, but nobody would write that!

(( 6 ))              // I want to be a oneple
( ( 6 ) )            // this also a oneple
( ( ( 6 ) ) )        // this also a oneple with a superfluous pair of parens, ambiguous
((  ( 6 )  ))        // superflous parens are innermost
(  (( 6 ))  )        // superfluous parens are outermost

((7 + 8) * (9 + 10)) // not a oneple, despite the (( ... ))
```

Those three examples with `6` inside three pairs of parens are ambiguous, I'm not bothered which of them the grammar takes, they're semantically the same. By the 'maximum munch' rule, it should take the middle of the three i.e. leaving the innermost parens as superfluous.

The lexer takes each `(`, `)` as a separate token. Currently the parser is taking `(` `(` `(` 6 `)` `)` `)` as equivalent to `6` (where that's parsed as `expr`/`int`) -- i.e. what the grammar did before I tried changing it.

The grammar has many levels of tokens defined by other tokens. Some expressions in some contexts are recognising the double-parens OK. Others not so much (and it's hard to boil this down to a reasonable-sized example). Are there any general techniques for persuading bison to take maximum munch?

**Addit:** This ambiguity is similar to the celebrated ambiguity in the very first language to use BNF: ALGOL 60

```
if cond1    then 
  if cond2  then blah2
 else            blah3;      // is this on cond2 False or cond1 False?
```

That was resolved by saying the `else` attaches to the innermost `if/then` that hasn't already got an `else` -- that is, on `cond2` False in this case; leaving `cond1` without an `else` branch. (ALGOL didn't have an 'offside rule', thank heavens!)

**Addit2:** OK, by popular demand, the yacc code before I started amending is [here](https://github.com/FranklinChen/hugs98-plus-Sep2006/blob/master/src/parser.y) (Now you're going to wish you never asked.) This for example is working in rule `aexp` (middle line is my mod)

```
  | '(' exp ')'         {$$ = gc3($2);}
  | '(' '(' exp ')' ')'     {$$ = gc5(buildTuple(cons($3,NIL)));}   /* ADC Apr-2020  */
  | '(' exps2 ')'       {$$ = gc3(buildTuple($2));}
```

This line is not working -- in rule `apat` the `pat` keeps being parsed as a multi-parenthesised ordinary pattern.

```
apat      : NUMLIT          {$$ = $1;}
  | var             {$$ = $1;}
  | '(' '(' pat ')' ')'     {$$ = gc5(buildTuple(singleton($3)));}  /* ADC Apr-2020 */
  | apat_vI         {$$ = $1;}
  ;
```

I have tried inserting that line in all sorts of places up and down the tree from `pat`; I've even tried putting it in multiple productions at the same time, which seems well dodgy. The parser consistently seems to ignore it.

Thank you for @Chris Dodd's answer. I thought that despite this giving shift/reduce errors, I had read on other SO answers that bison 'does the right thing' -- that is, if you put one production above another, it'll prefer that first.

Comment: Bison does not do.maximum munch; that's a feature of lexical analysis. it's not really a meaningful concept within a CFG.

Comment: Thanks. OK so the lexer is taking each `(`, `)` as a separate token. I want the grammar to take two `( (` together providing they pair with a closing two `) )`. If that's not 'maximum munch', is there another term for it?

Comment: You don't show your grammar, so its impossible to say what you did.  However, if you want (( to be treated as one or two tokens in different cases depending on future tokens, you're going to need more than one token lookahead.  You might be able to do something with bison's glr mode, but traditional yacc won't be able to do anything.

Comment: Thanks, no I'm happy to treat each `(`, `)` as a separate token -- in fact I must: see the last example I just added. I want to resolve this in the parser. So @rici tells me this isn't 'maximum munch' -- then I want 'maximum token-string'.

Comment: Why do do you think the three examples with 6 inside three parentheses are ambiguous? They aren't. And *all* the parentheses in those examples are redundant, not just one pair. Unclear what you're asking. Show your grammar.

Comment: Since there's no grammar (hint [POST YOUR CODE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)) there's nothing to be 'ambiguous'

Comment: And you want the grammar to take two (( together why? And what does this have to do with the if/else shift-reduce conflict?

Comment: @user207421 In my O.P. the examples "I want to be a oneple" demonstrate the grammar: the doubled-parens are not redundant, they're a constructor wrapping a value, distinct from the bare value. See also my answer, with more examples. Why do I want this? I'm implementing extensible tuples. What do you get when you project away an element from a twople; or extend a zerople with one element? A tuple with a single element is perfectly cromulent, just as a record with a single field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed this; it's nothing to do with `%left / %right` precedence.

Note in the **Addit2:** code that worked, there's the same non-terminal `pat` appearing in the two rules that are potentially ambiguous; and the terminals that differentiate them also appear (single pair of parens vs doubled-up pair). Whereas in the problematic example, the 'competing' non-terminals are differently named; and there's no terminals.

In those rules for `apat`, `NUMLIT` cannot start with `(`, neither can `var`. `apat_vI` might start with `(`, so move this rule for `pat` into it. (Look in the repo I linked to if you're following along at home.)

But it's not good enough to just move the rule into `apat_vI`. Here's the critical few lines:

```
  | '(' pat_npk ')'     {$$ = gc3($2);}   
  | '(' npk ')'         {$$ = gc3($2);}                  
/*    | '(' '(' pat ')' ')'     {$$ = gc5(buildTuple(singleton($3)));}      /*   ignored */
  | '(' '(' pat_npk ')' ')'     {$$ = gc5(buildTuple(singleton($3)));}  /* same non-term */
```

The commented-out line with `pat` is the one I moved, but it doesn't resolve the ambiguity. (And doesn't decrease the count of shift/reduce conflicts.)

Looking at the productions from `pat`, they're `npk` or `pat_npk`. In this case, `npk` can't begin with `(` -- so ignore it; `pat_npk` might. So change the `pat` to `pat_npk`, and that decreases the shift/reduce conflicts by 2.

`( ( ( 6 ) ) )` is now parsed same as `(( 6 ))`, differently to bare `6`. Here's a session using the language:

```
Main> let foo x = (( x )) in foo 6           -- (( x )) in exp always worked
(( 6 ))
Main> let bar (( x )) = x in bar (( 6 ))     -- (( x )) in pat got treated as bare x
6
Main> let bar (( x )) = x in bar (( (6) ))   -- three pairs of parens treated as a double
6
Main> let bar (( x )) = x in bar (( ((6)) )) -- four pairs of parens treated as two doubles
(( 6 ))
```

The critical characteristic is:

- bison must be able to see there's two productions within the rules for `apat_vI` that include the same non-terminal `pat_npk`; *and*
- that their context differs by terminals (a pair of parens vs doubled-up).
- Then upon meeting a `(` in the incoming token string, the parser will shift and wait to see if it gets another.

Just as in the if/else conflict: encourage the parser to shift the first `else`, and wait to see if it gets another.

Answer (score 0):

So you don't show your code, but I'm guessing you're trying something like:

```
%token NUM NAME
%left '+' '-'
%left '*' '/'
%nonassoc PREFIX
%%

expr: expr '+' expr
    | expr '-' expr
    | expr '*' expr
    | expr '/' expr
    | '-' expr %prec PREFIX
    | '(' expr ')'   /* parentheses for grouping */
    | NUM
    | NAME
    | '(' exprlist ',' expr ')' /* tuple */
    | '(' '(' expr ')' ')'      /* one-ple */
    ;

exprlist: expr | exprlist ',' expr ;
```

This grammar is ambiguous, and has one shift/reduce conflict stemming from that.  But the default prefer-shift-over-reduce resolution will result in it parsing with the "one-ple" rule rather than the "parentheses" rule twice.

However, if you add a `%left ')'` directive, it will resolve this the opposite way (and report a "rule useless due to conflicts" for the one-ple rule)

Comment: I don't want to resolve "the opposite way", as you say. So `%left ')'` is no help. So this is not an answer. According to the first-ranked answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13553837/bison-operator-precedence, I must pay attention to the "terminal itself appear[ing] in the ambiguous production". And indeed the cases where it works they did. But I've moved the rules that didn't so appear, it's no better. hmmm

Comment: If you don't want it that way, don't use `%left ')'`.  If what you have isn't working its probably because you have that (or the equivalent) and you just need to remove it.  But as you refuse to reveal the secrets of your grammar, noone can help you more.

Comment: According to here https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/html_node/Precedence-Decl.html, `%left` vs `%right` is to do with a symbol appearing twice or more infix between other non-terminals. That's not what I have. I have now revealed my whole `parser.y`.